add a custom tooltip for Apache superset dashboard
How to add a tooltip for superset dashboard? I searched the videos and documents but unable to find the solution.
I don't know  how to start.

This is not what Stack Overflow is for. We are not a tutorial site, nor are we a code-writing service.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
